# Angular 8 input two way binding for electron app doesn't work

Tags: electron, angular8, two-way-binding

**HTML**

```
<input [ngModel]="bar" (ngModelChange)="modelChangeFn($event)"> <p>{{ bar }}</p>
```

**for app.modules  :**
i import (FormsModule)

**For app.component  :**
i added  :

```
bar = 'World'; modelChangeFn(e) {this.bar = e;}
```

Comment: Attaching error log message will be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: Also try adding ````modelChangeFn(e) { this.bar = event.target.value } ```` rather than just e